# Carrierwave AWS No Change When Re-uploading Image with Same FIle Name

Tags: caching, amazon-web-services, carrierwave

I am currently using carrierwave-aws to upload to my S3 bucket.

One issue I am having is after the image is uploaded and saved, if the user, lets say changed something about the image locally and re-submitted for upload with the same file name, it will not reflect the new file uploaded.

The user has to change some part of the file name for it to show the correct one in my application.

I am assuming this is a caching issue but not sure where to begin to address this matter.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 1):

If your S3 bucket is set with a long or infinite expiry (which is a good idea for performance), you'll need to change the filename each time the image changes. See the [Carrierwave wiki page](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3a-Create-random-and-unique-filenames-for-all-versioned-files) on how to do this.